# Subprocess freezes popen().stdout.read

Tags: c++, python, subprocess, ipc, cout

I've got this problem bothering me for some time now and I can't seem to find a solution to it , I've been using subprocess.Popen() to access a C++ app that does some heavy calculations for me , but it keeps freezing on Popen().stdout.read();
here's the python code:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['/path/to/my/executable'], shell=False, 
stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
process.stdin.write("Some String")
print process.stdout.read()#It freezes here
```

and here's the c++ code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    ...Prep work...
    while (1) {
        string input;
        cin>>input;
    ...Some Work ...
        cout<< response;
    }
}
```

The c++ code works perfectly in shell , but I can't figure out why it freezes on python

Comment: Because the Python script waits for the sub-process to end?

Comment: can I read the cout without waiting for the process to end ?

Comment: If `process.stdin` is buffered, your writes may not be immediately visible to the C++ program. Likewise, if `process.stdout` is buffered, the C++ writes may not be immediately visible to your Python program.

Comment: You should be able to pass a length argument to `read()`, otherwise you'll be waiting for an EOF which you likely won't have until the subprocess completes.

Comment: Thank you for your response but i tried adding the length argument but still no output

Comment: What if you change the print statement to `print process.stdout.readline()`? And make sure your C++ code is appending newlines when it prints to `cout`.

Comment: Try replacing `read` with `readline` inside a while loop with the condition `while process.returncode is not None:`

Comment: Tried that , but it still freezes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `communicate()` instead:

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(['app'], shell=False,
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = process.communicate("Some String")
print out
```

Also, make sure you end your C++ process at some point. For example, when you reach the end of your input stream:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    //...Prep work...
    while (cin) {  // <-- Will eventually reach the end of the input stream
        string input;
        cin >> input;
        //...Some Work ...
        string response = input;
        cout << response;
    }
}
```

There is a warning for this in python's documentation:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stdin (right above)

It explains that when you write to your external app, data may be put in a queue. Also, your external app's output will also likely be put in a queue. communicate() will "flush" the content you are sending to your external app and wait until your app terminates.

Using `communicate()` will get the whole external app's output in memory. If it is not practical (huge output for example), you can then write or read using stdin and stdout objects. You'll need to take care of not "deadlocking":

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen(['app'], shell=False,
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
process.stdin.write("Some String")
process.stdin.close()  # <-- Makes sure the external app gets an EOF while
                       #     reading its input stream.
for line in process.stdout.readlines():
    print line
```

But even with this technique, make sure the input you give to the external app is small enough to avoid blocking while writing.

If your input is also quite big, you'll have to make sure your reads and writes are not blocking. Use of threads will most likely be a good choice then.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Teebrin, I tried it and now I'm getting this error                                                            out, err = process.communicate(command)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 806, in communicate
    return self._communicate(input)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1382, in _communicate
    stdout, stderr = self._communicate_with_poll(input)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1456, in _communicate_with_poll
    data = os.read(fd, 4096)
MemoryError

Comment: Your external app is probably outputing a huge amount of data. I edited my answer to give an example of how to read a huge output. In fact, it resembles a little more your original code.

Answer (score 0):

Typically we need non-blocking IO, 
1) read all replies until no more data and then 
2) emit something to the subprocess, 
repeating 1-2
Using threads will also help.